# Blank dashboard with no access

Tags: plugins, dashboard, user-access

[image]is there any idea how may i fix this issue (in a photo). I use reset wordpress plug-in last time and then it is happen. 
Regards,

Comment: Did you login with admin role ?

Comment: yes. I login as an admin role. its been 3 day i couldnt find any solutions. :"(

Comment: If you've just run a database reset then you don't have any data I guess, just a WordPress install with some plugins and themes installed and maybe a few uploaded files that are no longer in the media catalogue? I'd probably rebuild your site from scratch then.